# How to reuse class in models without using validation for all of them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have generic model for contact

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to use my contact class in two models but apply the validation only on second?

```
      public class Step1Model{
        public Contact Contact{get;set;}
      }

  public class Step2Model{
    [Requried]
    public Contact Contact{get;set;}
  }
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14072088/728795) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12712601/728795) threads look close to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You could move the annotations to a metadata type (see [`MetadataTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), but I suspect that would require having all the data annotations on the metadata type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided not to have many view models.

Here is my implementation

https://gist.github.com/cpoDesign/bc9c5980a89cfe7b0caf

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

1 - Code to an interface which will require you to create a ContactRequired class and a ContactOptional class based upon the ContactInterface.  I believe this will allow you to then have a single StepModel where you would set the StepModel.Contact property to either a new ContactRequired() or a new ContactOption().  Then when the validaiton runs for the StepModel, it will be have based upon the type of class you set for the StepModel.Contact property.

```
    public interface ContactInterface
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }
}
public class ContactOptional : ContactInterface
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
public class ContactRequired : ContactInterface
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
public class StepModel
{
    public ContactInterface Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
    StepModel smTest = new StepModel();
    ContactRequired crContact = new ContactRequired();
    ContactOptional coContact = new ContactOptional();
    List<ValidationResult> lErrors = new List<ValidationResult>();

    smTest.Contact = coContact;
    //Validate Option
    if (Validator.TryValidateObject(smTest, new ValidationContext(smTest, serviceProvider: null, items: null), lErrors, true))
    {
        //Code should reach this as the model should be valid;
    }

    smTest.Contact = crContact;
    //Validate Required
    if (Validator.TryValidateObject(smTest, new ValidationContext(smTest, serviceProvider: null, items: null), lErrors, true))
    {
        //Code should not reach this as the model should be invalid;
    }
```

2 - Create a custom required attribute which will look at another property of the Contact model (such as bool UseValidation) to determine if the required validation should even take place or if it should simply return true as the default.  I am not initially providing code for this option as you would need a custom attribute for every type of validation attribute in your class.  Also, I think option 1 is the better one unless you have a specific reason against it.